# How to translate input value letters into English using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am creating a simple application using Jquery, In my application, I want to limit user input language, for example, if the user will record Russian `б` in the input field I want to translate this input value letter into English charset. Here is a private example of what I'm trying

```js
$("#name").keyup(function() {
    var charsObject = {
        'а': 'a',
        'б': 'b',
        'г': 'g',
    };
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#name").keyup(function(obj) {
  var charsObject = {
    'а': 'a',
    'б': 'b',
    'г': 'g',
  };
  if (charsObject[obj.key]) {
    console.log(charsObject[obj.key])
  } else {
    console.log(obj.key)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name">
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will sanitize the input as you supply it, be it by typing or by using other methods (like pasting text using the right mouse button):

```js
$("#name").on("input", function() {
  var carr='бb,гg'.split(',').map(e=>e.split(''));
  let s=$(this).val();
  carr.forEach(([k,v])=>s=s.replaceAll(k,v));
  $(this).val(s)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name">
```

In this later version I replaced your `charsObject` by an array of arrays (`carr`) which can then be processed directly in the `input`-event handler.